# python pattern cutting of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, parsing, pattern-matching, cut

I have a dictionary variable "d" with key ,an integer, and value as a list of strings.

```
368501900 ['GH131.hmm  ', 'CBM1.hmm  ']
368499531 ['AA8.hmm  ']
368500556 ['AA7.hmm  ']
368500559 ['GT2.hmm  ']
368507728 ['GH16.hmm  ']
368496466 ['AA2.hmm  ']
368504803 ['GT21.hmm  ']
368503093 ['GT1.hmm  ', 'GT4.hmm  ']
```

The code is like this:

```
d = dict()

for key in d:
    dictValue = d[key]

    dictMerged = list(sorted(set(dictValue), key=dictValue.index))
    print (key, dictMerged)
```

However, I want to remove string after the numbers in the lists so I can have a result like this:

```
368501900 ['GH', 'CBM']
368499531 ['AA']
368500556 ['AA']
368500559 ['GT']
368507728 ['GH']
368496466 ['AA']
368504803 ['GT']
368503093 ['GT']
```

I think the code should be inserted between dictValue and dictMerged, but I cannot make a logic.
Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import this at the beginning

```
    import re
```

now use this line between dictValue and dictMerged

```
    new_dict_value = [re.sub(r'\d.*', '', x) for x in dictValue]
```

and then use new_dict_value in the next line

Comment: Regular expression and oneliner for loop!
That's it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

String objects have a nice `.isdigit()` method.  Here are some non-`re` solutions for cleaning your data.

Plain old loop:

```
values = ['GT1.hmm  ', 'GT4.hmm  ']
clean_values = []
for item in values:
    clean_item = []
    for c in item:
        if c.isdigit():
            break
        clean_item.append(c)
    clean_values.append("".join(clean_item))
```

list comprehension using a `StopIteration` exception to act as a `break` inside of a generator expression: (*Note* using this `stop()` method in a list comprehension doesn't work, it requires a generator expression, normally denoted by `()`, but inside of a `.join()` these are optional.

```
def stop():
    raise StopIteration

values = ['GT1.hmm  ', 'GT4.hmm  ']
clean_values = ["".join(c if not c.isdigit() else stop() for c in item) for item in values]
```

list comprehension using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) :

```
from itertools import takewhile

values = ['GT1.hmm  ', 'GT4.hmm  '] 
clean_values = ["".join(takewhile(lambda c: not c.isdigit(),item)) for item in values]
```

*Examples derived from:*

http://tech.pro/tutorial/1554/four-tricks-for-comprehensions-in-python#breaking_the_loop